# How do I achieve multi level component/template event handling in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular4-forms

I am working on a Angular 5 Project. I have one template (Template A) which contains some HTML elements. I am embedding this template in a sibling template (Template B) which has extended functionality over Template A. Template B has buttons etc.

> Template A

```
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
```

> Template B

```
 <html>
   <templateA></templateA>
   <button (click)="onSubmit()")
 </html>
```

Now my actual components(Component A-Z) only link to Template B as their templateURL(reusable).
Each component can have its own onSubmit() event, which is actually being triggered from Template B but each component will have its own definition.
This works fine.

What I want is to have a (onChange) event in one of the elements in Template A but each component which will have definitions in (Component A-Z).
[image]

Comment: this is way too broad, you're asking how to architect your application.  It sounds like you need to make clearer separation between the functions of your components and generalize the event outputs.  But this is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: can you be more elaborative in last statement > `What I want is to have a (onChange) event in one of the elements in Template A but each component which will have definitions in (Component A-Z).`

Comment: Basically, I want the Template A to communicate with Component A. Instead of the typical parent child comms, this will be parent-child-child comms

Comment: something like broadcast, right?

Comment: yes, something like broadcast. if a click is triggered on template A, all components extending Template B should be able to react to the event

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

create a service `a.service.ts` like:

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class AService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() { }
    sendEvent(eventName: string) {
        this.subject.next({ event: eventName });
    }

    getEvent(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

this service will be used in Component(A-Z). Whenever you want to fire/receive event subscribe for event in component as:

**Component**

```
eventName: any;
subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private aService: AService) {
    this.subscription = this.aService.getEvent()
          .subscribe(event=> { 
               this.eventName = event;  // Do whatever you want
               if(this.eventName == 'elemAClicked') {
                  // I guess what you want is here
               }
          });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
// method that would be used in template just suppose onClickAElem
onClickAElem() {
   this.aService.sendEvent('elemAClicked');
}
```

Comment: Thank You, will try this. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @bryan60, this is more of an architecture question rather than a problem specific to certain state of the application.

As per my opinion, you need to come up with a generic approach to share the data across multiple components using events.

This will lead to a flexible implementation which can then be used everywhere else in your application.

I have used such an event service based on observables in my angular app which allows components to fire events and other components can listen to those events -

> Event Service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { UUID } from "./uuid-generator";

export const GLOBAL_EVENTS = {
    Test_Event: "Test_Event";
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @class EventListener
 */
class EventListener {

    constructor(uuid: string, func: Function) {
        if (!uuid || !func) {
            console.error("required arguments not provided!");
            return;
        }
        this._uuid = uuid;
        this.func = func;
    }

    private _uuid: string;
    public get uuid(): string {
        return this._uuid;
    }

    public func: Function;
}

@Injectable()
export class EventsService {

    private eventsSubject: Subject<any>;
    private listeners: Map<string, Array<EventListener>>;

    public constructor() {
        //initialise listeners
        this.listeners = new Map();
        //initialise event subject
        this.eventsSubject = new Rx.Subject();
        //listen to the changes in subject
        Rx.Observable.from(this.eventsSubject)
            .subscribe(({ name, args }) => {
                if (this.listeners[name]) {
                    this.listeners[name].forEach((listener: EventListener) => {
                        listener.func(...args);
                    });
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Listens to the event and provides a unique key for the listener
     * @method on
     * @param {string} name name of the event to be listened to.
     * @param {Function} listener listener function with one array argument
     * @return {string} returns the key (UUID) for listener function which can be used to stop listening to the event.
     * @memberof EventsService
    */
    public on(name: string, listener: Function): string {
        this.listeners[name] = this.listeners[name] || [];
        let listenerEvent: EventListener = new EventListener(UUID.generate(), listener);
        this.listeners[name].push(listenerEvent);
        return listenerEvent.uuid;
    }

    /**
     * Stops listening to the event by using the unique key for the listener
     * @method off
     * @param {string} name name of the event to be broadcasted
     * @param {string} uuid name of the event listener specific uuid to be removed
     * @param {boolean} [removeAll=false] removes all event listeners attached to specified event name
     * @returns {void} 
     * @memberof EventsService
    */
    public off(name: string, uuid?: string, removeAll: boolean = false): void {
        if (!this.listeners[name] || !this.listeners[name].length) {
            return;
        }
        if (removeAll) {
            this.listeners[name] = [];
            return;
        }
        this.listeners[name] = this.listeners[name].filter((item: EventListener, index: number) => {
            return item.uuid !== uuid;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Broadcasts the event and passes data provided in args argument as event data
     * @method broadcast
     * @param {string} name name of the event to be broadcasted.
     * @param {any} args arguments to be sent with the event.
     * @return {void} return void
     * @memberof EventsService
    */
    public broadcast(name: string, ...args): void {
        this.eventsSubject.next({ name, args });
    }
}
```

> UUID Generator

```
export class UUID {
    public static generate(): string {
        return "your_hash";
    }
}
```

> Registering Event

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { EventsService, GLOBAL_EVENTS } from "./events.service";

@Component({
    selector: "[app-listener-component]",
    templateUrl: "./app-listener-component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app-listener-component.scss"]
})
export class ListenerComponent {

    private eventId: string;

    public constructor(private _EventsService: EventsService) {
        this.eventId = this._EventsService.on(GLOBAL_EVENTS.Test_Event, (response: any) => {
            console.log(response);            
        });
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._EventsService.off(this.eventId);
    }
}
```

> Broadcasting Message

```
import { EventsService, GLOBAL_EVENTS } from "./events.service";

export class BroadcatComponent
    public constructor(private _EventsService: EventsService) {
        let data: any = {
            message: "any"
        }
        this._EventsService.broadcast(GLOBAL_EVENTS.Test_Event, data);
    }
}
```

> Things to Remember

Make sure to add service in main app module so that it will start behaving as a singleton service throughout the application.

Every event subscription gives back a `UUID` string which can be used to remove the event handler in global scope (`additional features are in code comments`).

Using `ngDestroy` to remove event handlers would make sure unused events are not persisted in memory

`At last but not the least, I have modified the original code so you might get compilation errors in the sample code.`

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank You, will try this. Appreciate it :)